# AWS Error: An error occurred while starting the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2

I am deploying a .Net Core Web API 2.2 to AWS (Amazon). The environment of my app is healthy and i am still getting the following error and i know it has to do with the .Net Core Windows hosting on the server. How do I solve this please?

[image]

Thanks, 
Somad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first depolyed the .Net Core API app to my local machine.
I got EC2 Windows Server 2019 base installed on AWS Amazon.
I have installed .Net Core windows hosting 2.2.8 on the EC2 windows server and finally moved the api deployed file from my local machine to the EC2 windows server.
Below is a screenshot of the deployed app on the server:

[image]

Thanks,
Somad